# Python 'from x import y as z', what's imported?

Tags: python

**Disclaimer:** this question will likely have an answer already, but I can't find that specific answer, only broader ones.

I'm trying to understand what exactly happens when you do `from x import y as z`.

**fs.py**:

```
def foo():
    return 'spam'

def do_something():
    return foo()
```

**caller.py**:

```
from fs import do_something as do

def foo():
    return 'bacon'

print(do())
```

Run it:

```
>>python caller.py
spam
```

What's confusing me is that I specify "only import `fs.do_something`", but I *also get* `fs.foo()` implicitly (i.e. I didn't explicitly ask for it). Apparently, Python doesn't even look for `foo()` in `caller.py`.

In itself, it's quite handy that it works this way, because it allows you to separate sub-functions within a single, better testable, module. But wouldn't things get confusing if you have a lot of 'implicit' imports?

Comment: Wouldn't it be even more confusing if the importer would need to know and understand every dependency of the thing it's importing and import it as well?

Comment: The whole module is imported (if it hasn't been already), and then `do_something` from that module is bound to `do` in the current namespace.

Comment: Import doesn't copy the function into your code, it just makes it callable from your code, but it stays in its own module/package. Maybe that way of imagining it helps.

Comment: Think of modules as namespaces. You cannot simply override ``foo`` by defining it somewhere else, because ``module1.foo`` and ``module2.foo`` are totally separate things. You can however write ``module1.foo = foo`` in module2 and replace it that way for all calls (even for module3).

Comment: @Bernard Thank you, that does help.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't get `fs.foo()` implicitly.

If we "expand" the imports in-place (this is *not* how Python actually does things, but for the sake of illustration):

```
# (from fs import do_something as do)

def fs___foo():  # (this is _not_ actually visible in `caller`'s namespace!)
    return 'spam'

def fs___do_something():
    return fs_foo()

do = fs___do_something

# (end of simulated import)

def foo():
    return 'bacon'

print(do()) 
print(foo())
```

---

```
spam
bacon
```

---